# Animation not working after return to ViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, uiview, viewcontroller

I have the following code to animate a badge if a certain condition is met. It works fine, except when it is called immediately after the ViewController is re-loaded after a look-up (in another VC)

```
if ((-MY CONDITION HERE-) {
        NSLog(@"am going to animate!");

      [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                            delay:0
                          options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat)
                       animations:^{
                                  selectedInfoButton.alpha = 0.4;
                                 }
                       completion:nil];
   }
```

I can see that the method is called when the VC is re-loaded, but the animation is 'frozen' in the same state as when the look-up is called. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Before adding willy-nilly delays to the code, you can often find a way which fixes the problem properly.

Comment: InRainbows, where does the above code occur? Is it in viewDidAppear, for example? Or viewDidLoad?

Comment: Remove the repeat option and try.

Comment: @vishy - delay doesn't make it work

Comment: @occulus - this is where the problem is.

Comment: @AbdullahUmer - Removing option doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibility:

- One time works in  `viewController`

  the code is called in `viewDidLoad`
  method .Then add it in `viewWillAppear`
- Check the condition is satisfied,(that is the code hits in the block ) the second time the  ViewController reappers

Comment: By repeating the code call in ViewDidAppear, the animation is now working again. It doesn't with viewWillAppear!! Following the code with break points, I can see that the animation is called during viewDidLoad and BEFORE the segue transition to the VC with the animation in it. Presumably the segue transition kills the animation, hence starting the animation again after viewDidAppear gets it working. Thanks so much for your reply.